# Axonframework with Spring Boot: Query side cannot receive event in case of using JPA-based Repository on command side

Tags: spring-boot, axon

I have created a project [springaxon](https://github.com/atec2000/springaxon) with axon-spring-boot-starter for studying axonframework. .
It works fine if I using event sourcing on command side. (In fact, because JPA is available, and bean userOrderRepository is not declared, an Event Store with a JPA Event Storage Engine is used by default)
I can see the log "...received OrderCreatedEvent..." from query side. The following is related source code.

```
UserOrder.java:
@Aggregate
@Entity
public class UserOrder

AxonConfiguration.java:
//Do not declare a repository
```

I'd like JPA-based Repository on command side instead of event sourcing, so I annotated a repository for the aggregate, and declared this repository.
The following is related source code.

```
UserOrder.java:
@Aggregate(repository="orderRepository")
@Entity
public class UserOrder

AxonConfiguration.java:
@Bean
@Autowired
public Repository<UserOrder> orderRepository(EntityManagerProvider entityManagerProvider, EventBus eventBus) {
    return new GenericJpaRepository<UserOrder>(entityManagerProvider, UserOrder.class, eventBus);
}
```

But I cannot get the log "...received OrderCreatedEvent..." from query side this time.

I have no idea for this, any suggest is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting the type of repository you use for an aggregate shouldn't have any impact on the event bus capabilities, it just stores the events a little different.

The main adjustment it accompanies for events, is that they change from `DomainEventMessages` to regular `EventMessags` internally. 
The difference in this is that `DomainEventMessages` have aggregate specific field required for event sourcing your aggregate based on events.
And since you prefer to not event source the aggregate, there is no longer the need to use those `DomainEventMessages`.

That said, they should still be stored and thus retrievable from you're query side.

Did you verify your events are still stored in the event store?
Did you maybe also adjust your `EventStore` to an `(Simple)EventBus`? 
The default in Axon when using the Spring Boot starter dependency is an `EmbeddedEventStore`, which stores and sends events.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Steven. Yes, my OrderCreatedEvent are still stored in the event store, and aggregate was persisted in JPA database, but I cannot receive OrderCreatedEvent on query side. And, I didn't adjust any default components(command bus, event bus, etc), I just declared an orderRepository, it was wired with default entityManagerProvider and eventBus by @Autowired annotation. If I comment my orderRepository declaration out, it works fine.

Comment: First thing which comes to mind to further pinpoint the issue: I believe I saw that you've got two Spring Boot apps. One for the command side and one for the query side. Correct?
Did you try to put your event handling class from your query app in your command app? 
This is just a suggestion for tries to hopefully pinpoint what the issue is.

Comment: I created same event handler on command side, it cannot receive event too.

Comment: So I've done some test steps to make some Axon Labs were I am doing the thing which isn't working for you.
You can find the stuff on my GitHub page [here](https://github.com/smcvb/axon-labs/tree/lab-4/president).
It's pointing to the fourth branch (the fourth lab), as there I've got an EventHandling component which is called whilst I'm not doing Event Sourcing but have a `GenericJpaRepository` configured.
Maybe that code gives you some pointers why it's not working in your set up!

Comment: Thanks Steven, I'll try it like your git project.

Comment: Hi @JackZhou, did my suggestion resolve the problem? It would be beneficial, to anybody reading this, if you could suggest the course of action you've taken or mark my question as the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't work at that time and I am not sure whether it works fine for now. I could not figure it out on that version of axonframework at that time.